# Truncation in ML Part 2

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm nearly there on truncating a string in ML, but am getting an error about not handling an empty list.  Here's my code and the error:

```
fun getAllButLast([x]) = nil
    | getAllButLast(x::xs) = x::getAllButLast(xs);

fun truncate(myString, 1) = str(hd(explode(myString)))
    | truncate(myString, limit) =
    let
        val x::xs = explode(myString);
    in
        str(x) ^ truncate(implode(getAllButLast(xs)), limit - 1)
    end;
```

I load the file and call truncate("heythere", 5), which should give me "heyth".  Instead, I get this error:

```
uncaught exception Empty
  raised at: smlnj/init/pervasive.sml:209.19-209.24
```

This is pretty surprising since, as long as I input a limit number (the second parameter) that's $\ge$ 1, the string (or list of characters representing the string) should never be empty.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,
bclayman

Comment: Why not use limit = 0 as the basis case? In that case -- return the string unmodified.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sure, I could do that but that doesn't seem to solve my issue re: Empty exception

Comment: your current basis case returns just the first character. Don't you want it to just throw away the last?

Comment: @JohnColeman I want it to truncate everything after the first x characters.  So if I call truncate("h", 1) it should return "h".  Similarly if I truncate("hey", 1), it should still return "h".  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hint: there's a library function that does the same with lists. Combine it with `explode` and `implode` for a free solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dropping two characters at every recursive step: the first one (`x`) and the last one. So the length of the string reaches 0 long before `limit` reaches 1.

FWIW, here is a simpler solution to your problem:

```
fun truncate(s, n) = implode(List.take(explode s, n))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wanted to avoid using take or substring, just sticking with hd, tl, explode and implode.  I now have: 'fun `truncate(myString, 1) = str(hd(explode(myString)))
    | truncate(myString, limit) =
    truncate(implode(tl(explode(myString), limit - 1);` Tho still not quite right, heh.